# Why dismissing the presentingViewController, only dismisses the child controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have seen a couple of questions regarding this, but none helped me fix this issue.

I have a MasterViewController -> AViewController -> BViewController

Documentation says:

The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Calling this method from my B VC, should dismiss my A and B VCs. Yet, it only dismisses the child (B VC). Why?

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [myAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
    Work * newWork = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Work" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newWork setName:_workName];
    [myAppDelegate saveContext];

    NSLog(@"%@", [self.presentingViewController description]);
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

}
```

I don't know if it's relevant but, A and B VCs, are being presented like this:

```
    TWWorkNameViewController *controller = (TWWorkNameViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WorkName"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: No, it should only dismiss BViewController. If A presented B then writing [self dismiss..] (in B), and [self.presentingViewController dismiss..](also in B) are identical.

Comment: But shouldn't self.presentingViewController, be the A VC? I'm getting a description for A, from B, and I can confirm the method is being called in A from B. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes self.presentingViewController will be A, and since A presented B, A is dismissing the one it presented, which is B. When you say [self dismiss...] in the presented controller (B), that message is sent to controller A which does [self dismiss...], but now self is A since it was forwarded.

Comment: It's fixed now. Thank you kind Sir, for your very clear explanation and helping me understand this. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your MasterViewController is presenting the AViewController and this is presenting the BViewController so when you use [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; you are dismissing the BViewController because this is the one in the top of the stack, if you wan to go back to MasterViewController from the BViewController you can use a Navigtioncontroller and use the method

popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
"Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display."
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and if you don't want to use navigation controller you will need to use notifications:
in your MasterViewcontroller in the view did load do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(dismiss) name:@"BACKTOINDEXNOTE" object:nil];
}

-(void)dismiss
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

BViewController
inside your method just say

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender {
 NSNotification * notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"BACKTOINDEXNOTE" object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
}
```

So with this you will dismiss the BViewController and the AViewController.

Comment: I understand it now. I like your solution, but if I may, I'll also leave this one here, [[[self presentingVC] presentingVC] dismis...]; This goes down the stack (to the Master VC) and dismisses both A and B VCs. If there is any reason why I shouldn't do this. Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, "If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller." is referring to cases where the presented view controller itself is not presenting any view controllers. Normally, the presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented, but if you call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` on a view controller that hasn't presented anything, there are two options - either do nothing or dismiss it self. It makes sense that it dismisses itself by forwarding that message to its presenting view controller. If you call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` on a view controller that is presenting another view controller then it should dismiss that view controller and not forward the message to it's presenting view controller (if it has any) as the documentation says.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the correct answer, but if you have A->B->C and you are on C and want to get back to A, meaning dismiss C and B at the same time, you can use the presentingViewController of B.  I tested this with iOS 8. Both B and C are dismissed at the same time, in one animations.

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```